# In the CKEditor 5 Track Changes plugin, is there a way to turn on by default?

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor5

I have a react app using the CKEditor 5 track changes plugin. The button to turn change tracking on/off appears and functions, but I would like to be able to set it on or off by default. Is there a configuration option for this?

Answer (score 1):

In CKeditor5 you can turn track changes on and off by executing `trackChanges` command that is documented [here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/collaboration/track-changes/track-changes-api.html#commands). So basically, assuming you have onReady method, that runs when CKEditor is initialized with the instance of the editor, you can run this command like that:

```
onReady(editorInstance) {
    editorInstance.execute('trackChanges');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's based on which plugin you using, if you using Fite /Lite for track changes. the below code will do it.

```
CKEDITOR.on("instanceReady", function(evt) {
    evt.editor.config.flite.isTracking = true;
});
```

Comment: Your answer is related to CKEditor4, not CKEditor5